# application trouble

Tags: desktop, launchpad

I recently downloaded frost wire to my macbook air laptop. The application shows up on the desktop but I don't want it there. My question is how so I put the application in launchpad?

Comment: Have you tried dragging the app to your /Applications folder?

Answer (score 1):

Launchpad automatically grabs all applications in your root /Applications directory and in your /User/username/Applications directory. If you keep some of your apps in other locations, they won't appear in Launchpad automatically.

To add them to Launchpad, simply drag the app onto the Launchpad icon in the Dock. Or move the application to your main Applications directory or to your user Applications directory. Or make an alias of it and put the alias inside your Applications directory.